# How to call parent static method using child class in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, static-methods

I have a **java class** AAA with a static method:

```
public class AAA {
    public static void foo() {}
}
```

and a **kotlin class** which extends it:

```
class BBB : AAA() {}
```

Now in other **kotlin file** I would like to call that method. If I do it like this then it works:

```
fun bar() {
    AAA.foo()
}
```

but when I'm doing it like this it doesn't compile (Unresolved reference: foo):

```
fun bar() {
    BBB.foo()
}
```

Is it possible to call parent static method using child class BBB in kotlin? In java there is no problem with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, according to [Calling Java from Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html#accessing-static-members), this is how Java's static members are ported to Kotlin:

> Static members of Java classes form "companion objects" for these
> classes. You can't pass such a "companion object" around as a value
> but can access the members explicitly.

You don't inherit the companion object of a superclass in Kotlin.

```
open class A {
    companion object {
        fun foo() {}
    }
}

class B: A() {
    fun bar() {
        // this doesn't work because B.Companion does not exist
        B.foo()

        // these work, because these are implicitly A.Companion.foo()
        foo()
        A.foo()
    }
}
```

Technically, you could write a companion object in `BBB` that has all the static members of `AAA`:

```
class BBB : AAA() {
    companion object {
        // this allows you to do BBB.foo()
        val foo = AAA::foo
    }
}
```

Though I think that's beside the point.

That said, this doesn't really matter at the end of the day. Practically, you don't lose anything by doing `AAA.foo()`.

Comment: Thanks, as to "you don't lose anything by doing AAA.foo()", that's correct but the idea behind that was that we are trying to minimize number of dependencies to lib X which defines AAA, so from this perspective it would be better to be able to call BBB.foo(). Anyway, I understand that it's not straightforward, so thanks for explanation.

Comment: @LLL You can use a `typealias MyAAA = AAA`. That way you only have one "dependency", if I understand correctly.

Comment: Hiding that dependency by calling it via `BBB` doesn't make it go away. You still have the same dependency.